# React-QR-reader. The height and width of the video does not match the height and width video on the device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, qr-code, react-qr-code

The height and width of the video does not match the height and width video on the device.
Have styles component:

```
<QrReader
scanDelay={500}
onResult={handleScan}
ViewFinder={scanOverlay}
containerStyle={{ width: 300, height: 300, }}
videoStyle={{width: 300, height: 300, border: 'solid', borderWidth: '4px', borderColor: qrData.length === 0 ? 'red' : 'green', }}
constraints={{facingMode: 'environment'}}
/>
```

But video sizes are not 300x300. How to fix this?

[mobile camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBCQg.png)

[desktop camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFrec.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is related to the default **aspectRatio** so consider setting the aspect ratio constraints as follow:

```
constraints={{
  facingMode: 'environment',
  aspectRatio: { ideal: 1 },
}}
```

Full component code:

```
<QrReader
  scanDelay={500}
  onResult={handleScan}
  ViewFinder={scanOverlay}
  containerStyle={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
  videoStyle={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', border: 'solid', borderWidth: '4px', borderColor: qrData.length === 0 ? 'red' : 'green' }}
  constraints={{
    facingMode: 'environment',
    aspectRatio: { ideal: 1 }
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

npm install react-qr-reader

Check if you are using the correct version of the react-qr-reader library and that the library is up to date. Older versions of libraries may have issues that have been fixed in newer releases.